# Identifying properties that override base properties or implement interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-3.5

I am given:

- A class "`T`" which implements properties that are decorated with Attributes that I am interested in.
- A `PropertyInfo` "`p`" representing a property belonging to (1) an interface "`I`" that `T` implements, (2) a base class "`B`" that `T` inherits from, or (3) the class `T` itself.

I need to get the Attributes defined on (or inherited by) the properties in T, even if `p`'s DeclaringType is an interface that `T` implements or a class that `T` inherits from. So I need a way to get from `p` to the `PropertyInfo` that actually exists on `T`. Thus it seems that there are 3 cases:

1. #### `p.DeclaringType == typeof(T)`

   This is the trivial case. I can iterate through `T`'s properties until I find the match. Example:

   ```
   return typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                   .FirstOrDefault(property => property == p)
   ```
2. #### `p.DeclaringType == typeof(I)` where `I` is an interface that `T` implements

   This is more complicated. I found that I can use an InterfaceMapping to find the corresponding implementation of the `p` in `T`. It seems kind of hackish, but here what works:

   ```
   if (p.DeclaringType.IsInterface &&
       typeof(T).GetInterfaces().Contains(p.DeclaringType))
   {
       InterfaceMapping map = typeof(T).GetInterfaceMap(p.DeclaringType);
       MethodInfo getMethod = p.GetGetMethod();
       for (int i = 0; i < map.InterfaceMethods.Length; i++)
       {
           if (map.InterfaceMethods[i] == getMethod)
           {
               MethodInfo target = map.TargetMethods[i];
               return typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                               .FirstOrDefault(property => property.GetGetMethod() == target);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. #### `p.DeclaringType == typeof(B)` where `B` is a class that `T` inherits from

   I have not yet been able to figure out how to identify the property on `T` that overrides a virtual property `p` defined in `T`s base class `B`.

So my questions are

- In **case 3** how do I find the `PropertyInfo` on `T` that overrides the property `p` on `B`?
- Is there a better way to do all three? Perhaps a way to unify the three cases.

Comment: Whatever your solution ends up being, don't forget about the fact that a class can hide (or shadow) an inherited member (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28VS.71%29.aspx#vclrfnew_newmodifier).  That could possibly throw a wrench in your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to answer **case 3**. The key is `MethodInfo.GetBaseDefinition`

```
if (typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(p.DeclaringType))
{
    MethodInfo baseDefinition = p.GetGetMethod().GetBaseDefinition();
    return typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                    .FirstOrDefault(property => property.GetGetMethod().GetBaseDefinition() == baseDefinition);
}
```

However this only works for properties that have been overridden on `T`.

### Edit:

By comparing the following, it doesn't matter if the properties have or haven't been overriden on `T`:

```
property.GetGetMethod().GetBaseDefinition().MetadataToken == baseDefinition.MetadataToken
```

Comment: Big Fat Warning: as the documentation says, MetadataToken is only unique per Module. When testing your answer, by pure luck I happened to stumble upon two properties in the same class whose base getter method MetadataToken were the same because one of them was defined in another library. (The lucky part was that the class happened to be a *Test implementation of the base class and some of my tests failed.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a case : it is possible that `T` just inherits the property from `B`, without overriding it (unless you know for sure this won't happen in your specific scenario).

Anyway, you just need to search the property by name, using `typeof(T).GetProperty`, since there can't be 2 properties with the same name in a given class (unlike methods, which can have several overloads). However, you need to watch out for the case where `T` *hides* the property inherited from `B`, using the `new` modifier. To handle that case, you can check the `Attributes` of the property's getter method (obtained with `GetGetMethod`) : if the `NewSlot` flag is present, it hides the inherited getter.

Comment: When implementing interfaces explicitly, properties can have the same name.